# null reference exceptions when adding

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I discovered SubSonic this evening, and after a little bit of playing with it and MySQL Connector versions, I finally got it to accept my connection string setting up a simple repository.

So I created a simple class, and went to town adding some data to the class then creating a repo, and trying to save the record.

All I can seem to get out of it is null exception errors when I call:

repo.Add(user);

No idea what's null though, and the error isn't very clear.

At one point, I changed the type of my ID field in my User class to a long and got another error out of SubSonic (saying it couldn't tell what field was my ID field, telling me to name it ID or put a tag on it, but it was already named ID)

I've put data in every field in the class, even those that are not required per the database, but nothing.

I spent the rest of the evening googling for information on my error, but no luck, and the documentation on the site didn't get me anywhere either.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or how I could possibly diagnose this?

Thanks in advance for any help...

**Here's the exception details**

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=MySql.Data
  StackTrace:
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_ServerThread()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Abort()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at SubSonic.DataProviders.DbDataProvider.ExecuteReader(QueryCommand qry)
       at SubSonic.Query.Insert.ExecuteReader()
       at SubSonic.Repository.SimpleRepository.Add[T](T item)
       at gc_ss.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Michaelm\Desktop\Subsonic_Demo\gc_ss\gc_ss\Program.cs:line 27
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

**Another Update**

I'm noticing that if I change the class (User) and modify one of the properties, that the property changes get reflected in the database.  Also if I drop the table, it gets constructed based on my Class.  So the migrations part is working, it's something happening after that.

**Final Update**

Okay, I deleted the table, and changed the class to use a long as the ID field.  Set to RunMigrations, and ran again, and it failed because of no default value for ID.  I set the column in MySQL to AutoIncrement and all is working fine now.  Not sure how it's different than setting it to long yesterday (unless changes weren't getting applied like I thought they were).

Anyway, so I guess this question is closed...

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue with the mysql.data provider. Normally the connector would throw a meaningful exception but has an internal nullreference exception itself before that happens.

Look at my answer here: [Subsonic 3.0.0.4 ActiveRecord Template for MySQL error on inserting new record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118179/subsonic-3-0-0-4-activerecord-template-for-mysql-error-on-inserting-new-record/4143985#4143985)
That explains how to work around that.

Comment: Sorry, I was already back at home when I decided to post the question:

Comment: I updated my answer. You most likely have an error in your sql syntax for the generation part. Not every .net type is usable out of the box with subsonic. Look at the mysql.ttinclude there you have a method that does the mapping and I suppose for long you have to fix the string that defines the DBType (I would recommend BIGINT)