# SubSonic, GUIDs, and MySQL Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, mysql, subsonic, subsonic3

Now that I have Subsonic working, I decided to add another class and accomplish what I originally set out to do.

This entity class has just two properties, an ID property (type Guid) and a Name property (type String).

When I create an instance of the class, I set the Guid (using System.Guid.NewGuid()) so it has a value, then set the Name, and try to save the object.

```
repo.Add<TestingGuid>(test);
```

This is what I believe was causing my Null Reference exception in an earlier subsonic question.

The exception is (same as last question):

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>     Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     Source=MySql.Data
>     StackTrace:
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_ServerThread()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Abort()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at SubSonic.DataProviders.DbDataProvider.ExecuteReader(QueryCommand qry)
>          at SubSonic.Query.Insert.ExecuteReader()
>          at SubSonic.Repository.SimpleRepository.Add[T](T item)
>          at gc_ss.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Michaelm\Desktop\Subsonic_Demo\gc_ss\gc_ss\Program.cs:line 35
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException:

The entity class is simply:

```
namespace gc_ss
{
    public class TestingGuid
    {
        public static TestingGuid GetNewTestingGuid() 
        {
            TestingGuid row = new TestingGuid();
            row.ID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            return row;
        }

        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the program.cs running this is:

```
var repo = new SimpleRepository("gcdb", SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);

var test = TestingGuid.GetNewTestingGuid();
test.Name = "Mike";
repo.Add<TestingGuid>(test);
```

The database table got created just fine, with two columns, the ID column (Binary(16)) and Name (VARCHAR(255)).

It seems to just not like the Guid...

Any ideas?

Comment: just check whether repo variable is null?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but no, the repo, as is the test, objects are both set and working (the repo facilitated the creation of the table no problem).  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your other post, because of a bug in the connector, mysql is hiding the "real" exception from you.

[Subsonic 3.0.0.4 ActiveRecord Template for MySQL error on inserting new record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118179/subsonic-3-0-0-4-activerecord-template-for-mysql-error-on-inserting-new-record/4143985#4143985)